# Using PHP to display MySQL in HTML

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

**UPDATE: I have changed my_select_db and changed the row names to not have the # symbol.
It still doesn't work for me.**

I am new to using PHP and MySQL.  I have written a few pages using HTML, CSS, and JQuery.

I have a MySQL database that I am trying to display a few rows on a web page.

I am using XAMPP and running code locally. My website is located within the xampp htdocs folder.

Here is my HTML file partslookup.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.horizontalNav.js"></script>

    <script>
    // When document is ready...
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('.full-width').horizontalNav({}); // Call horizontalNav on the navigations wrapping element
        });
    </script>


    <script>
            function showUser(str)
            {
            if (str=="")
              {
              document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
              return;
              } 
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
              {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
              xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
              }
            else
              {// code for IE6, IE5
              xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
              }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
              {
              if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
              }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","livesearch.php?q="+str,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
            }
    </script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style-ie.css" />
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>

    <div id="page-wrap">
        <div id="inside">

            <div id="header">

            </div>

            <div id="menu">
                <nav class="horizontal-nav full-width horizontalNav-notprocessed">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Navigation Item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                        <li><a href="partslookup.html">Parts Look Up</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>

            <div id="main-content">                 

            <?php include 'livesearch.php'; ?>

            <div style="clear: both;"></div>

            <div id="footer">
                <p></p>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div style="clear: both;"></div>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

here is my PHP File livesearch.php:

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost:3306';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = 'password';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM ariens_prices';

mysql_select_db('taft_test1');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    echo "EMP ID :{$row['Part#']}  <br> ".
         "EMP NAME : {$row['Description']} <br> ".
         "EMP SALARY : {$row['Super#']} <br> ".
         "--------------------------------<br>";
} 
echo "Fetched data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

My database is named taft_test1, with a table named ariens_prices.
ariens_prices has 7 columns, only 2 of which I want to display called "Part#", "Description".

I have spent many days trying to figure this out to no avail.  I am sure I am just missing something silly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please take note that the mysql extension [is now **deprecated** and will be removed sometime in the future](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php). That's because it is ancient, full of bad practices and lacks some modern features. Don't use it to write new code. Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli_*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

Comment: I just wanted to note that both of the listed answers helped me.  My biggest problem was the fact that I was not parsing the PHP due to the fact that the browser was loading the file and not passing it to the local apache host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your DB is named "taft_test1", but your code is trying to use the tablename as your db name:

```
mysql_select_db('ariens_prices');
```

should be:

```
mysql_select_db('taft_test1');
```

Oh and, like the first comment says, these functions are deprecated.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

> **Warning** This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be
>   removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension
>   should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ
>   for more information. Alternatives to this function include:
>   mysqli_connect()
>   PDO::__construct()

***Updated*** - revised sql query to include only the columns you need. Also, I'm assuming the fields are named: Part#, Description, Super#

I would advise against the "#" symbol in a column name.

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost:3306';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = 'password';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$sql = 'SELECT Part#, Description, Super#  FROM ariends_prices';

mysql_select_db('ariens_prices');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    echo "EMP ID :{$row['Part#']}  <br> ".
         "EMP NAME : {$row['Description']} <br> ".
         "EMP SALARY : {$row['Super#']} <br> ".
         "--------------------------------<br>";
} 
echo "Fetched data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

It's wrong syntax

```
$sql = 'SELECT Part#, Description, Super#  FROM ariends_prices'
```

Correct way

```
$sql = 'SELECT \`Part#\`, Description, \`Super#\`  FROM ariends_prices'
```

"#" character can be a problem with Sql.

Comment: Actually you can: http://codepad.org/qaNMzUCX It doesn't make for highly readable code, but it's not a syntax error.

Comment: it's my bad sorry. I cannot see { }

Comment: When i try your code edited based on my db , its running. But, if i change any column name like us_name# , i get an error 'Could not get data: Unknown column 'us_name' in 'field list'. I thing # is special char for SQL queries.Therefore, sublime text show the text which is after the # character with different color ,so there is an problem in there.

Comment: you can write with "\`" , this is solve the problem . Ex: \`Part#\`